# How to control which Python version plpython3 uses?

Tags: python-3.9, plpython

I have a postgres 11 database running on CentOS 7 and am trying to use PL/python, but need to point to a specific version of the python interpreter. I need to use python3.9 whereas it is using python3.6. I am not able to uninstall python3.6 at the moment, so was hoping to point plpython3 at my python3.9 interpreter somehow.

I have installed the package postgresql-plpython3:

`sudo yum install -y postgresql-plpython3`

I have created an extension in PG and can run a simple PL/python function that reports the version used:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pyver ()
RETURNS TEXT
AS $$
    import sys
    pyversion = sys.version
    return pyversion
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpython3u';
```

Executing it returns this:

```
# select pyver();
                  pyver
-----------------------------------------
 3.6.8 (default, Nov 16 2020, 16:55:22) +
 [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
(1 row)
```

On my operating systems I have the following python interpreter files, and the versions they are using:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.9.6

$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.6

$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.8
```

Something within the plpython3 module seems to be hard-coded to point to my python3.6 version.

Comment: Python runtime needs to match the Postgres version. Seems to me that you need to upgrade Postgres to use python 3.7 or newer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

postgresql uses an **embedded** python interpreter, as stated [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython-envar.html). Changing it requires re-compiling the pl/python extension (afaik). Compilation instructions [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-procedure.html) show the relevant bits: the option `--with-python` and the env var `PYTHON`